# How to find which input value in a loop yielded the output min?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve a min value problem, I could obtain the min values from two loops but, what I really need is also the exact values that correspended to output min.

```
from __future__ import division
from numpy import*
b1=0.9917949
b2=0.01911
b3=0.000840
b4=0.10175
b5=0.000763
mu=1.66057*10**(-24) #gram
c=3.0*10**8

Mler=open("olasiM.txt","w+")
data=zeros(0,'float')
for A in range(1,25):
    M2=zeros(0,'float')
    print 'A=',A
    for Z in range(1,A+1):
        SEMF=mu*c**2*(b1*A+b2*A**(2./3.)-b3*Z+b4*A*((1./2.)-(Z/A))**2+(b5*Z**2)/(A**(1./3.)))
        SEMF=array(SEMF)
        M2=hstack((M2,SEMF))
    minm2=min(M2)    
    data=hstack((data,minm2))
    data=hstack((data,A))
datalist = data.tolist()

for i in range (len(datalist)):
     Mler.write(str(datalist[i])+'\n')
Mler.close()
```

Here, what I want is to see the min value of the `SEMF` and, corresponding `A`,`Z` values, For example, it has to be `A=1`, `Z=1` and `SEMF= some#`
I also don't know how to write these, `A` and `Z` values to the document

Comment: Where are `zeros`, `array`, and `hstack` defined? Are they Numpy functions? If so, you need to add the `numpy` tag to your question. Otherwise, people won't know that you're looking for a Numpy solution.

Comment: I believe, I corrected the beggining part. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Wait, in your loop is `SEMF` just a number? I don't see why you are doing that loop and adding elements one-by-one using `hstack` when you could use some vectorized operation instead... create the array `As = np.array(range(1, 25), dtype=float)` (choose appropriate `dtype`), then obtain the `SEMF` array by doing the same operations you are doing with `A` but using the array instead, then you'll have the array of all the results and you will be able to do `the_mins = min(SEMF)`. You may be able to vectorize the outer loop as well...

Comment: In any case: note that using `from numpy import *` is *dangerous*. For example you are overriding functions like built-in `min` and `max` with `numpy`'s versions which is going to break any code that uses `min` and `max` but doesn't expect to use the numpy variants. The "standard" way is to `import numpy as np` and then use `np.min`, `np.max`, `np.array`.  This also makes it clear what comes from `numpy` and what not. You can also import just the names you need: `from numpy import (array, min as np_min, hstack, zeros)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big advantage of numpy over using python lists is *vectorized operations*. Unfortunately your code fails completely in using them. For example the whole inner loop that has `Z` as index can easily be vectorized. You instead are computing the single elements using python `float`s and then stacking them one by one in the numpy array `M2`.

So I'd refactor that part of the code by:

```
import numpy as np
# ...

Zs = np.arange(1, A+1, dtype=float)
SEMF = mu*c**2 * (b1*A + b2*A**(2./3.) - b3*Zs + b4*A*((1./2.) - (Zs/A))**2 + (b5*Zs**2)/(A**(1./3.)))
```

Here the `SEMF` array should be exactly what you'd obtain as the final `M2` array. Now you can find the minimum and stack that value into your `data` array:

```
min_val = SEMF.min()    
data = hstack((data,minm2))
data = hstack((data,A))
```

If you also what to keep track for which value of `Z` you got the minimum you can use the `argmin` method:

```
min_val, min_pos = SEMF.min(), SEMF.argmin()  
data = hstack((data,np.array([min_val, min_pos, A])))
```

The final code should look like:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

b1 = 0.9917949
b2 = 0.01911
b3 = 0.000840
b4 = 0.10175
b5 = 0.000763
mu = 1.66057*10**(-24) #gram
c = 3.0*10**8

data=zeros(0,'float')
for A in range(1,25):
    Zs = np.arange(1, A+1, dtype=float)
    SEMF = mu*c**2 * (b1*A + b2*A**(2./3.) - b3*Zs + b4*A*((1./2.) - (Zs/A))**2 + (b5*Zs**2)/(A**(1./3.)))  

    min_val, min_pos = SEMF.min(), SEMF.argmin()  
    data = hstack((data,np.array([min_val, min_pos, A])))

datalist = data.tolist()

with open("olasiM.txt","w+") as mler:
    for i in range (len(datalist)):
        mler.write(str(datalist[i])+'\n')
```

---

Note that numpy provides some functions to save/load array to/from files, like [`savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) so I suggest that instead of manually saving the values there to use these functions.

---

Probably some `numpy` expert could vectorize also the operations for the `As`. Unfortunately my numpy knowledge isn't that advanced and I don't know how the handle the fact that we'd have a variable number of dimensions due to the `range(1, A+1)` thing...